# Flickr API JSONP signed with callback

Tags: callback, jsonp, call, flickr, signed

Having issues with the Flickr API. In a nutshell, I've got a signed call that works fine, but I need to add a callback to it. Adding `&callback=?` to the string causes the API to return `jsonFlickrApi({"stat":"fail", "code":96, "message":"Invalid signature"})`

So I'm not sure how to best approach it. The call needs to be signed because it's grabbing private photos. Is there a way to structure my callback function to avoid the problem? I've been putting the callback after the format parameter and have tried at the end of the string. Both return the same error. Am I misplacing it?

Thanks for your help!

jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/RzkzY/14/

```
function imgBuilder(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo,function(i,rPhoto){
        var base   = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret,
            thumb  = base + '_m.jpg',
            medium = base + '.jpg',
            large  = base + '_b.jpg',
            imageM = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ medium +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>',
            imageL = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ large +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>';

        $(imageM).appendTo("#test");
    });
}

/* Need to add callback to the string?? */ 
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e3571d0891d2ad7f6b2b44611b8126ee&user_id=26545877%40N04&tags=terminal+5&per_page=25&format=json&auth_token=72157629563488548-bdcd1a2ad2f288df&api_sig=944625b8e72de2b3b9200a892263e1b1", imgBuilder);​
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar with the Remember the Milk API, which I think was based on the Flickr API.

I've managed to make a successfull call by over-riding jQuery's defaults for the JSONP request.

jQuery adds a `callback=` and `_=` parameter to the request by default. Flickr will include these parameters when calculating the signature of your request. It doesn't match the `api_sig` you calculated, so the request fails.

`callback=` is used to relate the response to your callback function and is generated by jQuery so you can't include it in your signature calculation, but you can over-ride the default behaviour and specify it yourself by including

```
jsonp: false,
jsonpCallback: 'my_callback_name',
```

as parameters to your `$.ajax` call.

I assume `'my_callback_name'` should be unique for each load of the page containing the ajax call. You should include `callback='my_callback_name'` in the parameters when you calculate the api_sig.

`_=` is a timestamp added to the URL by jQuery to make each request unique, which again you can't know at the point you calculate the api_sig. You can prevent it being added by adding

```
cache: true,
```

This will stop the `_=` being added to your URL (and invalidating the `api_sig`) but it could lead to caching of the ajax-fetched-data, which you may not want.